# QGIS Contour Vectors to Raster

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, vector, contour

I'm wanting to create a DEM from vector contours but whatever tool I use, it fails to identify the sea level contour at elevation 0.

I have tried via GRASS v.to.r, QGIS tool Vector to Raster and QGIS TIN functionality.The DEM is to include both topography and bathemetric contours to enable tsunami analysis.

If I temporarily change the 0 contour to 10 of course it works, but it needs to be 0.

Comment: Are the contours lines or polygons?

Comment: The contours are lines.